# The aggregation pipeline is not enabled for this account

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I try to execute a mongoDB aggregation pipeline against [Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction) via a Node.js application. I use the `mongodb` package with version `3.6.2` to connect to the cloud ressource.

While the pipeline runs without any error in the Azure Portal, I got an error within the Node environment.

> MongoError: The aggregation pipeline is not enabled for this account. Please see https://aka.ms/mongodb-aggregation for details.

The linked resource seems outdated, because the mentioned Azure Portal entries don't exist anymore.

(My pipeline contains a `$group` expression. Without the `$group`, it returns a result.)

I guess, the problem is related to my client setup, since it works within the Mongo Shell.

```
async function aggregate<T>(pipeline: Record<string, unknown>[]): Promise<T[]> {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(COSMOSDB_URL), {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    auth: { user: COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT_NAME, password: COSMOSDB_PASSWORD }
  });
  try {
    // Returns the error
    return await client.db().collection('coll').aggregate<T>(pipeline).toArray();
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions, how to fix the issue?

Comment: Seems a similar issue as described in the azure-docs repository - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/45723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, that the `url` passed to `MongoClient.connect()` differed from the *Connection String* in the Azure Portal.

```
// Returns error "The aggregation pipeline is not enabled for this account". 
const COSMOSDB_URL = `mongodb://${account_name}.documents.azure.com:10255/${database_name}`;

// Correct URL taken from the Connection String (HOST) in the Azure Portal
const COSMOSDB_URL = `mongodb://${account_name}.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/${database_name}`;
```

While `db().collection().find()` works for both URLs, `db().collection().aggregate()` works only for the second one.

Finally I found the correct naming rule in the Azure documentation, where it got an extra section - [Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB (3.6 version): supported features and syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36#protocol-support).